# MySql Fetch rows that have latest date

Tags: mysql

Here's the code:

```
SELECT        tblitem.strItemCode, tblitem.strItemName, tblitemunit.strItemUnitName, tblvendor.strVendName, MAX(tblitemprice.dtmItemPasOf) AS Expr1, 
                         tblitemprice.dblItemPAmount
FROM            tblclassification INNER JOIN
                         tblitem ON tblclassification.strClasCode = tblitem.strItemClasCode INNER JOIN
                         tblitemprice ON tblitem.strItemCode = tblitemprice.strItemPItemCode INNER JOIN
                         tblitemunit ON tblitemprice.strItemPItemUnitCode = tblitemunit.strItemUnitCode INNER JOIN
                         tblvendor ON tblclassification.strClasCode = tblvendor.strVendClasCode AND tblitemprice.strItemPVendCode = tblvendor.strVendCode AND tblitem.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY tblitem.strItemCode, tblitem.strItemName, tblitemunit.strItemUnitName, tblvendor.strVendName, tblitemprice.dblItemPAmount
```

And Here's the Result:

```
CODE     NAME        UNIT    VENDOR          DATE            PRICE

ITEM101-Fudgee Bar-Piece-Imus Palengke 10/9/20165:03:32AM - 6.5

ITEM102-Yum Burger-Box-Jollibee Lumina Mall-10/9/2016 6:13:27 AM  -    2500

ITEM102-Yum Burger-Piece-Jollibee Lumina Mall-10/9/2016 4:42:28 AM  -  30
ITEM102-Yum Burger-Piece-Jollibee Lumina Mall-10/13/2016 12:37:31 PM-  35

ITEM102-Yum Burger  Piece   Jollibee Lumina Mall    10/14/2016 10:05:44 PM  40
```

What I want to happen is to fetch only the row with the latest price. Can someone help me please.

**I want to fetch the Item101 and only the last row to ITEM102 since it is the latest.**

Comment: I want to fetch the last row only to ITEM102 since it is the latest.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you're looking for the last updated row price. It's easy to do so:

1. Order your data by their relevant timestamp in reversed order (`ORDER BY <FIELD_NAME> DESC`). From what I gather from your query and results, `Expr1` is the latest date for a given price.
2. Only pick a single element (`LIMIT 1`). Since your data is already ordered in reverse chronological order, you're sure to pick the latest one.

The SQL for that would be

```
SELECT        tblitem.strItemCode, tblitem.strItemName, tblitemunit.strItemUnitName, tblvendor.strVendName, MAX(tblitemprice.dtmItemPasOf) AS Expr1, 
                         tblitemprice.dblItemPAmount
FROM            tblclassification INNER JOIN
                         tblitem ON tblclassification.strClasCode = tblitem.strItemClasCode INNER JOIN
                         tblitemprice ON tblitem.strItemCode = tblitemprice.strItemPItemCode INNER JOIN
                         tblitemunit ON tblitemprice.strItemPItemUnitCode = tblitemunit.strItemUnitCode INNER JOIN
                         tblvendor ON tblclassification.strClasCode = tblvendor.strVendClasCode AND tblitemprice.strItemPVendCode = tblvendor.strVendCode AND tblitem.deleted_at IS NULL
GROUP BY tblitem.strItemCode, tblitem.strItemName, tblitemunit.strItemUnitName, tblvendor.strVendName, tblitemprice.dblItemPAmount
ORDER BY Expr1 DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Try it out !